# ajax function not passing value to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, image

Help me please!

I have  a `div` with couple of images of some banks in my `_layout.cshtml` page. Each image has an `id`, let's say `id "Jonota","Sonali","Rupali"`...etc. Now, I am using `jquery`, so that when each `image` is `clicked`,
I want to pass the `id` of that image to my `controller`.
My jquery looks like:

```
var a = $('div#banksBody img').size();
a.each($('div#banksBody img').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('bankIcons');  // this class is just for making the cursor > pointer in css 
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/Test",
        type: "POST",
        traditional:true,
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result!="") {
                alert(result);
        }
    });         
}));
```

My controller looks quite simple:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Test(string id)
    {       
        return Json(id , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The title suggest that no value is passed to the controller, but in your question you make no further clarifications upon your problem. Does it enter your controller, but it does not have a value for the string? Or does it not get to the mapped method at all?

Comment: May be try this, change this from `var id = this.id;` to `var id = $(this).id;`

Comment: Is your controller even being hit? You amy want to use `"/Home/Test` (note the extra `/`), or the link will only work if your page is in the root.

Comment: sorry for that. Yes it enters the controller. I tried the change you mention. Still i get null as return.

Comment: Then I think Prasanth has already provided the right answer. :)

Comment: i tried all the answers, but still no result. I mean still getting null as return.

Comment: You can try the following link, 



[Click the Link]


 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486132/jquery-ajax-passing-value-from-mvc-view-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply parameter name in post request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Home/Test",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id' : JSON.stringify(id)}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code `data: JSON.stringify(id),` I think **stringify** needs one more parameter

Insted of that try this :

```
data: {"id":id},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
         $("#banksBody>img").each(function() {


        $(this).click(function(){


          var id = $(this).attr('id');


            });


          });
```

Comment: first u have to apply each function for image not for image size ..then within that you can add click function for all images

Comment: thanks. but clicking each image is not the issue. My problem is,  I can't get image id to pass inside my controller.

Comment: In click function you can use this code to get the id             var id = $(this).attr('id');

Comment: i know. But i want to pass this id to one of my controller called "Home/Test" by an ajax function. Something like                        $.ajax({
        url: "Home/Test",
        type: "POST",
        traditional:true,
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result!="") {
                alert(result);
        }
    });  should be inside your click function. But i cant solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#banksBody>span").each(function() {


$(this).click(function(){


var id = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Test",
    type: "POST",
    traditional:true,
   data: {id:id},
   dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result!="") {
            alert(result);
    }
    });           
       });


    });
```

Comment: when i do it the way (only jquery part works. and that's i know), the ajax function does not get inside the controller. but if i use Json.stringify(id), then it gets inside the controller but id is not passed into the controller. And i get null as return.