# ASP.NET with JQuery AJAX causing "Bad Request" error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm getting a "bad request" error when I try to HTTP post to the "Home" controller using the following JQuery/AJAX. Does anyone see the cause?

This is pretty much a copy of the example obtained from here, except greatly simplified: [JQUERY ajax passing value from MVC View to Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486132/jquery-ajax-passing-value-from-mvc-view-to-controller). It seems it's not finding the controller, which confuses me -- I've fiddled with this a lot, and with no success.

Button in the view that throws a "bad request" error, and does not reach the controller:

```
<td> <input type="submit" class="btn-default" name="submit" value="Start Simulating-Jquery" id="btnSaveComments" />
            <script>     $('#btnSaveComments').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%:Url.Action("SaveComments")%>',
                        type: "post",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (savingStatus) {
                            alert("save")
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.toString())
                            alert(ajaxOptions.toString())
                            alert(thrownError.toString())
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </td>
```

Example of a button in the view that **does** work:

```
                     @Ajax.ActionLink("ActonLinkTest", "SaveComments", "Home",
                                new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    HttpMethod = "POST"
                                }
                            )
```

Controller (Home):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveComments()
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

EDIT: This also fails.

View:

```
<td>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-default" name="submit" value="Start Simulating-Jquery #2" id="btnSaveComments2" />
            <script>
                $('#btnSaveComments2').click(function () {
                    var comments = 'a';
                    var selectedId = '1';

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%: Url.Action("SaveComments")%>',
                        data: { 'id': selectedId, 'comments': comments },
                        type: "post",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (savingStatus) {

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert('failed')//$('#lblCommentsNotification').text("Error encountered while saving the comments.");
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </td>
```

Replacing the previous savecomments function with this one in the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveComments(int id, string comments)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the data portion of your ajax call.

Comment: cache: false adds an additional url param to your request (and isn't needed for post requests), could that be causing your problem? I'm not too familiar with asp.net, but the error you are getting is likely caused either by the url, or the post vars you are sending (or not sending).

Comment: I'm new with Jquery ajax, so it may have been stupid, but I ripped out the data segment of the call as part of a last ditch attempt at getting it to work. I'll edit & put it back in another example that does not work.

Comment: @KevinB, thank you for the suggestion - I tried removing cache:false from my examples, although that did not solve the problem either.

Comment: One problem is that the signature of SaveComments shows an Id (int) and a message (string) as parameters; however, your test is sending 2 strings, which the framework won't map correctly due to the mismatch of data types.

Comment: @Icarus, I was scrambling to revert back to my previous test- but I saw that as well and fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out. Question - now that it's mapped to "1", is it going to map to the string "1" or the int 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

```
var id = 1;
var comments = 'abc';
    $.ajax({
        data: { 'id': id, 'comments': comments },
        url: '/Home/SaveComments1',
        cache: false,
        success: function (savingStatus) {
            alert("save")
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.toString())
            alert(ajaxOptions.toString())
            alert(thrownError.toString())
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but you are doing a GET not a POST.

Comment: Good idea! I tried this already before posting the question, but I tried it again. It's not working - although that is indeed the correct URL to the controller.      What are your javascript includes? Maybe there's something obvious that I'm missing? -- jquery-1.10.2.js, jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js, jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: not more then <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: please look at the answer

Comment: This works! I'd like to be able to use the url helper, since it doesn't care about the path... but this works!
Oddly enough, it works whether my controller's parameters are string, string, or string, int

Comment: I'd mark this as the correct answer if you could make this edit - doing the same thing, but essentially in a slightly more safe way - add the parameter `data: { 'id': id, 'comments': comments },` to the ajax section, and change url to `url: '/Home/SaveComments',`. I'd paste my working code, but the way these comments are formatted won't let me do it (and I'd feel like a jerk for taking all your work and marking my own thing as the correct answer).

Comment: Yes this is the secure way to communicate with ajax so I have update the my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
url: '<%= Url.Action("SaveComments") %>',
```

I think you have the wrong inline tag.

Comment: Tried this change, it's still failing, unfortunately.

Comment: add an `alert('<%= Url.Action("SaveComments") %>');` to see what url you are trying to call, also was it the same error? and plz put semi colons at the end of your javascript statements :)