# MVC prompt on actionlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I found this code for confirm window, but I want to create a prompt window and pass the info user provided to controller (dunno how to grab the value and put it into routeValues :/ ).

It should work like this :

1. user clicks action link
2. prompt
3. controller gets the values from prompt

**Code :**

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
"Add", 
"Add", 
new { id = item.foo}, 
new { onclick = "return confirm('foo');" }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a prompt with one parameter, you can try to use Window prompt() here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

If you need more parameters, you can try Modal of bootstrap: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp (the last example)

Comment: I know how to use a prompt. I just don't get it how I could send the data to controller via action link. After using prompt when clicking ActionLink, I get the data to a variable in Javascript, which I don't know how to pass to a controller.

Comment: You also try some key word on google, such as: "pass data from view to controller", "pass data to controller via ajax"...

Comment: @Valium: You can use $.ajax() (post) to send data to controller.
We have an example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486132/jquery-ajax-passing-value-from-mvc-view-to-controller
Because, you use asp. net MVC, you need some changes:
$.ajax({url: 'Controller/Action', type: 'POST', data: {para01: value01, para02: value02}, success: funnction() {...} })
Notes: para01 and para02 need to be the same as name of parameter of action.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi 

If you have an action in MVC  Control Like :**

```
public ActionResult SetOkReject(int? RequestId,string MSG="")
    {
      //. . .
    }
```

**Convert ActionLink to a tag Like this:**

```
<a href='#'  onclick = 'return Reject(@Model.ElementAt(I).ID)' 
> Reject the request</a>
```

**And In Javascript write a function like:**

```
<script>
 function Reject(RequestId)
   {
      var T = confirm(' Do you reject this request?');
      if (T)
      {
        var Prom = prompt("Please enter the reason for 
            rejecting the request", "");

          if (Prom == null || Prom == "") {
              // nothing 
          } else {


              var curl = ActRejext + '?RequestId=' + RequestId + '&MSG=' + Prom;
              window.location.href = curl;
              return true;                   
          }          
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
</script>
```