# MVC5 Updating Database with Javascript Variable

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

To begin, I am very new to MVC.

1. I have a SQLEXPRESS Database named `MyDB` and a table named `Users`, Also the `ID` column is set to `Primary AutoIncrement`
2. I Have created my database connection in the Solutions Explorer.
3. I have created a class in my Models folder for my Dababase Connection

   ```
   namespace WebApplication1.Models
   {
       public class MyDB
       {
           public int ID { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public string Company { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<MyDB> Users { get; set; }
        }
   }
   ```
4. After Building the solution, I right-clicked on `Controllers` and created a new controller.
5. After the scaffolding I am left with this:

   ```
   namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
   {
       public class MyDBsController : Controller
       {
           private MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();

           // GET: MyDB
           public ActionResult Index()
           {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
           }

           // GET: MyDBs/Details/5
           public ActionResult Details(int? id)
           {
               if (id == null)
               {
                   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
               }
               MyDB myDB = db.Users.Find(id);
               if (myDB == null)
               {
                   return HttpNotFound();
               }
               return View(myDB);
           }

           // GET: MyDBs/Create
           public ActionResult Create()
           {
               return View();
           }

           // POST: MyDBs/Create
           // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
           // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
           [HttpPost]
           [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
           public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Company")] MyDB myDB)
               {
                   if (ModelState.IsValid)
                   {
                       db.Users.Add(myDB);
                       db.SaveChanges();
                       return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }

                    return View(myDB);
                }

                // GET: MyDBs/Edit/5
                public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
                {
                    if (id == null)
                    {
                        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                    }
                    MyDB myDB = db.Users.Find(id);
                    if (myDB == null)
                    {
                        return HttpNotFound();
                    }
                    return View(myDB);
                }

                // POST: MyDBs/Edit/5
                // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
                // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
                [HttpPost]
                [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
                public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Company")] MyDB myDB)
                    {
                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            db.Entry(myDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                         }
                         return View(myDB);
                     }

                     // GET: MyDBs/Delete/5
                     public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
                     {
                         if (id == null)
                         {
                             return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                         }
                         MyDB myDB = db.Users.Find(id);
                         if (myDB == null)
                         {
                             return HttpNotFound();
                         }
                         return View(myDB);
                     }

                     // POST: MyDBs/Delete/5
                     [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
                     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
                     public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
                     {
                         MyDB myDB = db.Users.Find(id);
                         db.Users.Remove(myDB);
                         db.SaveChanges();
                         return RedirectToAction("Index");
                      }

                      protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
                      {
                          if (disposing)
                          {
                              db.Dispose();
                          }
                          base.Dispose(disposing);
                      }
                  }
              }
   ```

I copy and pasted that whole block so excuse any brackets not matching up, I tried my (almost) best.

6. Now on my `Index.cshtml` under the `Home` folder I have a script:

   ```
       <script>
           $name = "John";
           $company = "123Moving";
       </script>
   ```
7. How do I get these values in my Database?

## What I have tried

```
<script>
$('a').click(function () {
    $name = "John";
    $company = "123Moving";

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "MyDBsController")',
        data: { 'Name': $name, 'Company' : $company },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr + ajaxOptions + thrownError);
        }

    })
})
</script>
```

Error I get is `[Object object] error not found`

Comment: Show us your script and how it is linked to `Index.cshtml`

Comment: There's nothing really on the page just an empty bootstrap grid. The script data i just located after my `.row`

Comment: You get those values to your server-side code either 1) with AJAX or 2) populate and submit a form with your client-side script variables.

Comment: @Jasen that's what I've read but I'm not sure what URL i send it to via ajax

Comment: [Here's an AJAX example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486132/jquery-ajax-passing-value-from-mvc-view-to-controller). It uses the older style asp markup but that's easily replaced with Razor e.g. `@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")`.

Comment: @Jasen can you double check my ajax call, I'm getting an error.

Comment: First, it should be `@Url.Action("Create", "MyDBs")`. Next, use `console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)` instead of `alert()` -- You can view this output in the browser's debugger (F12) which provides much better details. And since you are clicking an anchor tag you'll need to [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or you'll get default browser behavior which you don't want.

Comment: @Jasen
Ok I did all that and now the error I'm getting is `Failed to Load Resource Internal Error 500 http://localhost:59736/MyDBs/Create`

Comment: Drop `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` for now to get this to work -- you'll need to add that after you get the basics working. After all of that if you still get a 500 error you'll need to trap that on the server or configure IIS to report error details back to the browser. Error 500 is catch-all and not very informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example. I removed the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` which you can add later. You're doing an AJAX post so returning a full view isn't what you want. Instead, return a html fragment (partial view).

```
public class MyDBsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyDB myDB)
    {
        // do stuff...
        return PartialView("Success", myDB);
    }
}
```

**Success.cshtml**

```
@model MyDB

<h2>Success</h2>
<p>@Model.Name Created!</p>
```

Setup a div placeholder to report the result.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<a href="#">Create</a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Your AJAX request is triggered off an anchor tag so you must disable default behavior. `ControllerName` shouldn't include "Controller".

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $name = "John";
    var $company = "123Moving";

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Create", "MyDBs")",
        data: { "Name": $name, "Company" : $company },
        type: "post",
        success: function (partialViewResult) {
            // insert response into the div placeholder
            $("#result").html(partialViewResult);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of `alert()` use `console.log()` to get much better details through the browser's debugger.