# How to access ViewModel on the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I am learning MVC and I am trying to understand how to access the ViewModel at the controller level.

My question is how do I access the ViewModel in MethodTwo?

- Do I need to send the ViewModel back in the AJAX call?
- Is there a simple way just to be able to access the View Model in that method?

For example:

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int MyID { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I have this:

```
public ActionResult MethodOne(int myId, string myString, bool myBool)
{
    MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel { MyID = myId, MyString = myString,yBool = myBool };
    return View("MyPrint", mvm);
}
```

On my MyPrint page I am doing an Ajax GET (to the same controller) and I want to access that same ViewModel.

```
public string MethodTwo()
{
    // How can I access the ViewModel here???
    //var myString = DoStuff(MyViewModel);
    return myString;
}
```

Comment: In order to access the model's values in `MethodTwo`, you need to pass it to `MethodTwo`. If you're doing a GET request this would be values in the querystring.  What does the ajax request look like?

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Main/MediaReach/GetPrintData',
                contentType: 'text/html',
                data: {
                    mrpm: @Model
                }
            }).done(function (result) {
                $("#abc").append(result);
                print();
            }).fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            });

Comment: @JDS Use ModelBinding technique to get the data in Model inside controller. [Nice](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx) tutorial here.

Comment: You can't just pass the MVC model as a parameter unfortunately. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486132/jquery-ajax-passing-value-from-mvc-view-to-controller) is very similar.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I will research.  However I must be going about this the wrong way.  Basically I want to pass data from one page to another. (Which I accomplish view the ViewModel) However I want that data available for the MethodTwo call. (No manipulation will ever occur on the View)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but generally, if you want access to something in a method, you must pass it in as a parameter:

```
public string MethodTwo(MyViewModel model)
```

That would allow you to call it from another action like:

```
public ActionResult MethodOne(int myId, string myString, bool myBool)
{
    MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel { MyID = myId, MyString = myString,yBool = myBool };

    var result = MethodTwo(mvm);

    return View("MyPrint", mvm);
}
```

However, if you're talking about actually calling another action method, that's a bit different. If you need to load another action, then that requires redirecting the user to that new action. It also means that you must pass any data you need along with that redirect, and since a redirect will result in a GET request being issued, all you have to play with is the query string of the URL you redirect to. Trying to pass an entire class instance in a query string is inadvisable. You either have to flatten it into key-value pairs or you have to JSON encode it into a string that can be passed, which means you'd then have to JSON decoded it on the other in.

Since you're actually constructing the view model instacne based on simple type parameters in the first action, I'd recommend just passing these same type parameters to the second action and reconstructing it there, as well.