# My ASP.NET Core button not sending anything at all (ASP.NET Core MVC and C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have written this button but it is not working fine, it is not invoking the create HTTP method in the controller file:

Tale a look:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CODE" class="control-label">Code:</label>
                <input name="CODE" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NAME" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                <input name="NAME" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table" id="Tabla4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CODE)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CODE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After clicking on "Insert" button it does not do anything and my Create method is not even called in the Controller file (null parameters)

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind] Clients clients)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.InsertData(clients);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(clients);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Been searching and trying to solve it but it seems I'm not doing it correctly, I'm super lost in here. What should i correct?

Can help me?

Comment: @marc_s do you believe me if i tell you that it is added by it's own? Tha's strange

Comment: Sorry, @marc_s :)

Comment: Hey - it's not about making *me* happy - it's about ensuring your tags match your question so that there's a bigger chance for **YOU** that someone will be able to help and folks trying to help won't be confused by conflicting information

Comment: what is the view's corresponding controller? have you tried turning on the inspector tool of your browser and take a look at the `Network` tab? the most possibly wrong thing is the url is not found. Also try having a look into the `Output` window, it should report some possible silent error there, there are code (such as for model binding) that may fail before and your action will not get hit in such cases.

Comment: @KingKing My button is the problem in here, it is not working properly, it is not like the "common" asp.net button that is created automatically. Is it okay? Would you change something?

Comment: I don't care if you use `asp.net core` or the old `asp.net`, the same steps can be applied. You have your browser's developer tools & the powerful Visual Studio. That should be almost enough for you (in this scenario) to find out what's wrong first. BTW, I can just be guessing, cannot help you change something.

Comment: Ensure you have HttpPost attribute marked on the action. Also specify the controller name in the form tag just to be sure

Comment: @Qudus Yeah, it is related to that. I changed different things but my buttons is not INVOKING or you may say calling the Create method located in the Controller file. It is like it is not performing the operation at all.

Comment: you said as if it was disabled, so it's possibly a client-side issue, there may be some javascript code intercepting the `onsubmit` of your form and discarding it. Try creating a blank page or at least ensure that you have a clean page with just minimum code you have with that button to see if the issue remains.

Comment: `After clicking on "Insert" button it does not do anything and my Create method is not even called` As @KingKing suggested, please check if a request with expected data is made to `Create` action in browser f12 developer tool Network tab. If there no request is sent while you click the "Insert" button, please check if any client side script prevent the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your view receive a collection of `MyApplication.Models.Clients` and when you click on the submit button, you send a collection of `Clients` to controller.

So if you want to send an object of type `Clients` from view to controller, you should create another action and view that receive one model of `MyApplication.Models.Clients` like bellow.

Create view:

```
@model MyApplication.Models.Clients

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CODE" class="control-label">Code:</label>
                <input name="CODE" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NAME" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                <input name="NAME" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
     return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Clients clients)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.InsertData(clients);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(clients);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. The case is that i would like to put everything together. I'm using @model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients> because that is given me a list and i want to create a Create button on that view. So, it should be CREATE + LIST but that's where my problem is

Comment: Is there exist any way to put them all together?

Comment: It is not possible to put :model MyApplication.Models.Clients and model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Clients> in the same file

Comment: If you want to put them all together you should use **Ajax** to send data. you should set an event on submit button and when user click on the submit button you should send data from controller from view to controller by **Ajax**.

Comment: Really? how would you achieve something like that?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486132/jquery-ajax-passing-value-from-mvc-view-to-controller) maybe helpful for you